# Как переопределить перегруженные операторы базового класса

Tags: c++, ооп

```
class Triad
{
private:
    int a, b, c;
public:
    virtual bool operator == (const Triad &tf)noexcept
    {
        return ((a == tf.a) && (b == tf.b) && (c == tf.c));
    }
};

class Date : public Triad
{
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    bool operator == (const Date &dt)noexcept override
         ^^^^^^^
    {
        return ((day == dt.day) && (month == dt.month) && (year == dt.year));
    }
};
```

Comment: Взять и переопрелелить. Точно так же. Почему возник такой вопрос?

Comment: Не получается, так как тип передаваемых параметров разный. В базовом передаю Triad а в производном Date. Из за этого 
"объявленная с использованием ключевого слова override функция-член не переопределяет член базового класса"

Comment: А к чему тут вообще виртуальность? как по мне, тут как раз нужны два невиртуальных оператора - чтоб было понятно, что с чем сравнивается...

Comment: Если уж наследуетесь, то наверное стоит использовать `a`,`b`,`c` из базового класса, а не создавать новые поля. Тогда и `operator==` не нужно будет переопределять.

Comment: Ым... Почему код в вопросе поменялся так, что теперь не имеет ничего общего с исходным вопросом??? Если вопрос о переопеределении *виртуального метода*, то почему сначала никакой виртуальности даже близко не было?

Comment: Реализовать один оператор для одного класса, а второй для другого? Получается два независимых класса, но второй наследуется от первого? @Harry

Comment: Если вы сравниваете с `Triad` - то это *совсем другое* сравнение, чем с `Date`. Вы можете сравнивать `Date` и с `Triad`, и с `Date` - но по-разному. Только внесите в `Date` имя -     `using Triad::operator==;`, ну и я бы делал эти операторы константными. Ну, а насчет наследования - это же вы зачем-то наследуете `Date` от `Triad`, добавляя еще три поля...